# How to zip a text file and post it using NSURLConnection in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a text file in which I write all the NSLOG's and I post it to the server whenever required. Since I want to optimise the size of the file that is sent to the server , I want to zip the text file . I referred a lot of examples but could not clearly understand . This is my code to create the file

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logger.txt"];
NSString *logFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
freopen([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
```

and this is the code to post the file to the server.

```
NSString *finalURL = [self getSupportServletURL:persist];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:finalURL];
NSMutableURLRequest * requests = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
[requests setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[requests setValue:@"text" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Logger.txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
LogInfo(@"Data being posted to server %@",finalURL);
LogTrace(@"Post Data : Data being posted to server \n%@",content);
[requests setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
[requests setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[requests setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[content length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:requests delegate:self];
```

and this works perfectly. Can anyone help me in converting this to a zip file ( including the things that need to be included in .m file & .h file ) and posting it to the server . Thank You in advance.

Comment: look at [this](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) library.

Comment: I have loads of examples like these @mahesh but i ain't clear with the header inclusions and stuff .. So can you explain if it's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create logger file following way. I just created file in different directory instead of document directory so we can zip that directory.

```
//creating logger file in document directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//logger file name
NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logger.txt"];

//we will add log file in "LogFiles" directory so we can zip that directory
NSString *logFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/LogFiles/%@",fileName]];


//"LogFiles" directory path
NSString *LogFilesDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/LogFiles"];
NSError *error;

 //create "LogFiles" directory if not created
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:LogFilesDirectory])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:LogFilesDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

//writing logger file
freopen([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
```

Now 
    #import "SSZipArchive.h" in viewController.m

To create zip file use following code

```
//getting logger.txt file path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *logFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/LogFiles"]];

NSString* zipfile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/LogFiles/Logger.Zip"]];
//create zip file, return true on success
BOOL isZipCreated=[SSZipArchive createZipFileAtPath:zipfile withContentsOfDirectory:logFilePath];

    if (isZipCreated) {

    NSLog(@"Zip file Created at Path : %@",zipfile);
    NSData *zipData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:zipFile]; // note, autorelease object

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [zipData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/zip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:zipData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:requests delegate:self];

}

else
{
    NSLog(@"Zip create error");
}
```

Comment: And what should be the set value for the HTTPHeaderField "Content-type" ? Application/zip ?? .zip??

Comment: @ManeeshSharma yes, it's application/zip or application/octet-stream.

Comment: "SSZipArchive.h file not found" is the error being displayed when I import it in the .m file @Mahesh

Comment: did you install it?. if not then install it from [here](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive).

Comment: Install as in you mean adding "libz.dylib and libsqlite3.dylib" from \usr\lib ?? If yes , I have done that

Comment: If not , Please tell me what exactly do u mean by "install it"

Comment: i mean did you add the SSZipArchive and minizip folders to your project?
and  the libz library to your target ?

Comment: When I open ZipArchive-master , there are folders namely ObjectiveC example , swift example and SSZipArchive .. So I should the drag the SSZipArchive folder to the project ?

Comment: yes, exactly. when you drop it in the project please check the copy items checkbox.

Comment: try `#import "SSZipArchive/SSZipArchive.h"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116661/discussion-between-maneesh-sharma-and-mahesh).

Comment: I Should tell that @Mahesh nailed it . Thanks .